# Laravel eloquent patter search not working properly

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to query database using the user input value for search field. 
But the result i am getting is totally wrong. It doesn't have the search term.
I have no idea where i could be doing wrong. i followed the l`aravel doc`,and some questions over `stackoverflow`, but nothings seems to be working.
Can anyone please check my query and perhaps can guide me to the right direction.

My query is like this  `Query` term is `Rose` , and only one record has title name `Rose`

```
public function catelogSearch(Request $request){

    if ($request->has('query') && $request->get('query')!= ''){
        $searchQuery = $request->get('query');

        $query = ProductCategory::with(['product'=>function($q) use($searchQuery){
            $q->where([
                ['product_type','both'],
                ['title','LIKE','%'.$searchQuery.'%'],
                ]);

            if(request()->segment(1)=='shopping'){
                $q->orWhere('product_type','shop');

            }elseif (request()->segment(1)=='subscription'){
                $q->orWhere('product_type','sub');
            }
            $q->whereHas('price',function ($q){
                $q->where('quantity','>',0);
                $q->where('status',1);
            });
        }])->with('product');

                $data['result']=$query->paginate(30)->toArray();

            print_r($data);

}
```

This query giving me all the data in my database, unlike where it should give me where it has the query term in the title. And also please see, that i am querying `with('product')` two times. If i do one time, It doesn't return product data, it return empty response for the product.

Can anyone please suggest me.
Thank u.

**url :** `localhost:8000/shopping/catalogsearch/result?query=rose`

Model relations
**ProductCategory.php**

```
 public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
    }
```

**Product.php**

```
public function price(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductPrice');
    }
```

**product_category table**

```
    -----------------------------------------------
   id | product_id| category_id | sub_category_id |
    -----------------------------------------------
```

**Product table**

```
----------------------------
id | title | slug | product_type |
-----------------------------
```

**product price table**

```
----------------------------
id | product_id| price| quantity |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: you are simply overriding the first subquery with the second !

Comment: you mean second with('product')?? 
Even if i do not give that it gives the same response only diff is that, it do not give me product details

Comment: yeah post how url param will look like and the model relationships, I will help you how to build a search filter!

Comment: Hi, i updated my question with model relatiion url query link and table structure

Comment: Do you want to select products or product categories?

Comment: Only products and their prices from the price table

Comment: Hi, did you get the answer or not??

Comment: @Arunjai nope. Still cant figure it out

Comment: Can share me your product_categories table.

Comment: @Arunjai hi i added the product to category table

Answer (score 0):

```
       public function catelogSearch(Request $request){
            if ($request->has('query')){
             $searchQuery = $request->get('query');
             $query = ProductCategory::product;
             $query = $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchQuery.'%');
             if(request()->segment(1)=='shopping'){
              $query =  $query->where('product_type','shop');
            }elseif (request()->segment(1)=='subscription'){
              $query = $query->where('product_type','sub');
            }else{
              $query = $query->whereIn('product_type',array('shop','sub'));
}
         $query = $query->price->where('quantity','>',0)
                  ->where('status',1)->get();
dd($query);
        }
    }
```

I have removed these code which I will add it later once u get the desired output of the above one.so please try and let me know the output.

```
 if(request()->segment(1)=='shopping'){
                $q->orWhere('product_type','shop');

            }elseif (request()->segment(1)=='subscription'){
                $q->orWhere('product_type','sub');
            }
```

Comment: Hi,The section you removed is important. 
Basically it means select*from product_category with product, where product type is (both and 'sub/shop' ) and where title = %query.
Something like that, I hope that make sense . I am not very good with SQL query

Comment: Okay i got it now hold on let me edit i was confused with the word both now it is clear

Comment: Can you check now

Comment: its giving error 
`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$price`

Comment: Before  this line $query = $query->price->where('quantity','>',0)
                  ->where('status',1)->get();
put dd($query); see what you are getting